# Kvaser's CAN library has been loaded, but program executable outputs a "No module named 'can.interfaces.kvaser'" error

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, can-bus

I made a working application that successfully uses the python-can module to receive incoming messages on a kvaser CAN bus. When I used PyInstaller to convert this program to an executable file, the terminal logged that it "loaded kvaser's CAN library." The outputted .exe GUI runs as normal, yet the program suddenly doesn't receive any more CAN messages like it had beforehand. In the terminal, I printed the error it catches:

"Cannot import module can.interfaces.kvaser for CAN interface 'kvaser': No module named 'can.interfaces.kvaser".

Note that in the .spec file that I used to create the executable, I added "import can.interfaces.kvaser" at the top. I am not sure if the error I am getting is because I am not using pyinstaller correctly or if it is because I am somehow importing the CAN dependencies incorrectly, yet I suspect it is likely due to the latter. Is there a different way to import the python-can kvaser module that may solve this discrepancy between CAN functionality of the program before and after it was converted to an executable?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. It turns out that PyInstaller specifically installs the dependencies at the top of the main file you want to execute. Dependencies in other python files that you import into the main file aren't detected by PyInstaller. I added all the import calls I needed to the main file and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with Vector implementation in pysintaller, No module named 'can.interfaces.vector'” error.

the fix is as Erika Lu described, add below lines in your main file;

```
import can
import can.interfaces.vector
```

then you won't get error for;

```
 bus = can.interface.Bus(interface='vector', app_name....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to add these modules into pyInstallers *hiddenimport* list. E.g.:

```
a = Analysis(['myscript.py'],
         pathex='C:\\mypath\\src'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=['can.interfaces.kvaser', 'can.interfaces.vector'],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
```